# Iterate with foreach in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a few tags in XML :

```
<Process name="list-of-values" order="2">
    <CountryList name="USA" order="1" />
    <CountryList name="UK" order="2" />
    <CountryList name="INDIA" order="3" />
</Process>
```

And XSL file contains below template :

```
<xsl:for-each select="/Processes/Process/CountryList">
    <xsl:variable name="aggregationOrder" select="@order"/>
    <xsl:if test="$aggregationOrder='1'">&lt;ok to="<xsl:value-of select="@name"/>"&gt;</xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
<xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
</xsl:if>
```

Currently I am fetching only one value from my `<Process>` tag of order=1, I want to iterate all the names with according to order(integer value in countryList xml tag). As I should be getting USA,UK,INDIA based on there order value. Say initially order is '1' it should fetch 'USA' then order value increased by 1 then it should get 'UK' and so on.
I have tried below code :

```
<xsl:for-each select="Processes/Process/CountryList">
    <xsl:variable name="aggregationOrder" select="@order"/>
    <xsl:if test="$aggregationOrder='1'">&lt;ok to="<xsl:value-of select="@name"/>"&gt;</xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
<xsl:variable name="aggregationOrder" select="$aggregationOrder + 1"/>
<xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
</xsl:if>
```

But did not work for me. Any help on it?

Comment: Your question is not clear. It sounds like you want to **sort** the `CountryList` nodes by their order attribute? And what is the deal with outputting markup as text? What is your expected result here?

Comment: Your `for-each` and `if` tags are overlapping, and I don't think this stylesheet will even run.

Comment: @michael.hor257k I dont want to sort them, I want to fetch each name based on the order.

Comment: @MohitRane If you don't want to sort them, then I am afraid I don't know what "*fetch each name based on the order*" means. Please edit your question and add the expected output of the transformation.

Comment: @michael.hor257k sorry for the confusion made, I have updated the questions

Comment: @MohitRane What you describe **is** sort. And you still haven't posted the expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the following example input (which is slightly different from your own, in order to demonstrate the principle):

**XML**

```
<Process name="list-of-values" order="2">
    <CountryList name="INDIA" order="3" />
    <CountryList name="USA" order="1" />
    <CountryList name="UK" order="2" />
</Process>
```

the following stylesheet:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/Process">
    <output>
        <xsl:for-each select="CountryList">
            <xsl:sort select="@order" data-type="number" order="ascending"/>
                <country>
                    <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
                </country>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </output>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

will return:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<output>
   <country>USA</country>
   <country>UK</country>
   <country>INDIA</country>
</output>
```

Comment: michael.hor257k, thanks for the help. Thats what I wanted, is there any way in which we can increment the value of order like in java order++.

Comment: Why would you need this?

Comment: Coz I want one one country at a time and in the next iteration once the order integer value is '2' it will give 'UK'

Comment: @MohitRane I am afraid I have no idea what you're talking about. The proposed solution outputs one country at a time. If you have an example where this is not the expected result, please edit your question and include that example, showing both the input and the expected output.

Comment: @michael.hor257k There is one more foreach loop above the one that i have mentioned. So let say that for loop gives me one element as "One" so next for loop should give me "USA" and then the inner loop (that i have mentioned) will increment the order value by 1.
So expected output should be like this 
<One>
<ok to="USA"/>
</One>
<Two><ok to="UK"/><Two>

The One,Two values are from outer for loop.

Comment: @MohitRane This is not useful. Please edit your question and add all the necessary information there - **including the expected output**. I will not ask again.

Comment: @michael.hor257k Is that helpful or should I send more details.

Answer (score 1):

**XSLT**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:template match="/Process">
        <root>
            <xsl:variable name="initial" select="1"/>
            <!-- alternativ:
                <xsl:variable name="initial" select="@order"/> <- this selects the attr. "order" of element "Process"
            -->
            <xsl:for-each select="CountryList[@order &gt;= $initial]">
                <ok to="{@name}"/>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </root>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Explanation:**

You can set the variable `initial` to your start-value. The loop begins and searches for `CountryList`, which attribute `order` is greater or equal to the variable `initial`. Output will be a element `ok` with attr `to`.

*The order of the input-elements maintain.*

**Result, if you set `initial=2'**

```
<root><ok to="UK"/><ok to="INDIA"/></root>
```

**EDIT 1 (see comment below)**

I think you don't need to iterate at all. You can select directly via the Xpath. See here:

```
<xsl:template match="/Process">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="CountryList[@order=2]"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="CountryList">
    <ok to="{@name}"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I need one country at a time.
Say initial is 1 : so it will give me <root><ok to="USA"/><root>.
When initial value in incremented it to '2' it will give me 
<root><ok to="UK"/><root>, and so on.
I dont want to fetch all countries at one go

Comment: see my Edit in answer

Comment: But it will give me the country name with order '2', am I right ?
Cant we increment the oder value to 1. Something like order+1, so that when the next iteration comes it will give me country name whose order in 3.

Comment: I am getting this error : 
 Line #961; Column #39; xsl:template is not allowed in this position in the stylesheet!
For this line :     <xsl:template match="CountryList">

Comment: "when the next iteration comes" Do you want to execute the xslt x times?!

Comment: Dont forget to wrap it by `<xsl:stylesheet...`.